# Simultaneous use of an api key and an access token in the OAuth2 authorization flow

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

I'm auditing an API whose client is a mobile application using the OAuth2 workflow but I'm missing something. I have a first endpoint of the /token.oauth2 API which allows me with credentials to get an access token needed to call other endpoints of the API. So far OK but on top of that I have an "x-api-key" which is transmitted along with the access token and if both the API key and the access token are not present, the server sends me a HTTP 401 response. 
I can't find any mention of a connection flow using both an "x-api-key" and an access token in the OAuth2 standard. When do you think?